# Missing argument in controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting this warning below for one of my controllers, but its not just about warning, it actually doesn't do the work because of this missing argument.

I checked the controller file and I see that I'm already sending 3 arguments.
In the object.php file of cakephp, on line 127, I see the following: 
return $this->{$method}($params[0], $params[1]);

This program was running well for months, but suddenly yesterday, it started showing this warning and the problem.

Here is the warning, I get,

```
Missing argument 3 for SomeController::Report(), called in ...../web/content/bolt/cake/libs/object.php on line 127 and defined [APP/controllers/Somecontroller.php, line 32]
```

P.S : I changed the controller name here for this question.

Comment: Check your database. Your schema might have changed which means your model isn't correct. Make sure the db hasn't been migrated, and that your credentials are correct.

Comment: Also, please include some controller code, as the problem won't be in `object.php`

Comment: Backtrack over what you did yesterday. Something must have changed. Or it's a latent bug that has been waiting for its moment.

Comment: Seems like I found the cause, this code was fetching data via the API, but unexpectedly the API was not sending any data. I will have to do some tests although to make sure this was the cause.

Comment: Ah yes! Always check to make sure that you can reach remote sources before working with them ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could go for the debug_kit plugin, which gives more verbose information, e.g it provides you with some context, which could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the argument in your controller to null. like PostsController($ID = null)